# How to store a "dynamic" server name in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following meta tag in my HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://server_name:port/mypage"/>
```

The problem is that **server_name** is hardcoded value, I just want to get that value from server on demand (every HTTP request). How to do that?

Comment: Have you considered using a server-side 301 redirect?

Comment: Which server? The one it runs on? What did you tried already?

Comment: You'll need a server-side language for that, e.g. PHP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Comment: @radscheit Yes, the one it runs on. My app is running on Python webapp framework.

Comment: I agree with @j0